# Android Studio3.0 Error Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-2

this is my model gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "cn.xpcheng.dagger2demo"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    includeCompileClasspath true
                }
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
        annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
    }
```

this is my project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I make Project ,Android Studio give me this messages:

Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.

> Could not resolve com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   No cached version of com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13 available for offline mode.

I tried to clean and rebuild the project many times,but it do not works,
I feel very confused about this,can anyone help me?

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: yeah ,I tried to do this many times ,but it do not works

Comment: try to delete build folder and rebuild that will solve your problem hopefully

Comment: google() in allprojects and projects node in build.gradle???

Comment: my build.gradle has been uploaded,can you check it for me?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? Without a proxy between?

Comment: I'm sure I'm connected to the internet.

Comment: Let me clarify my question: Is your gradle build connected to the internet? The message says something about: _not available in offline mode_

Answer (score 1):

Same error faced by me.

Clean/Re-build not working for me.

**Solution**

> Edit the app level build.gradle (just add some white space) & click
>   sync now

Hope this help atleast anyone